# Violation of independence to be in multiple groups?

Tags: anova, independence

Ideally, I'd like to run an ANOVA across a variable regarding group membership on a continuous outcome variable. The problem is that each individual can be in multiple groups, which I believe violates the independence assumption. Is there another test I can run to compare group means? I could also eliminate those subjects that are in multiple groups, but that would bias the data. Any thoughts?